# How instance a C# Generic<T> class from ActionScript RemoteObject?

Tags: generics, flex4.5, remoteobject, fluorinefx

Is it possible to create an instance of a C# Generic class from Flex with RemoteObject and source?

```
remoteObject = new RemoteObject("fluorine");
remoteObject.source="Service.GenericClass`1"; //how specific the entity class??
remoteObject.getMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

I'm getting this error messages:

> Cannot create an instance of Service.GenericClass``1[T] because
>   ContainsGenericParameters is true.

This makes sense because I'm not specifying the entity class, but, how I do that??

I'm using FluorineFx for the remoting.

Comment: @Dan: note that the `**` bold commands don't work in code formatting. It's sometimes annoying...

Comment: @sarnold I should have removed those out of there (not sure why I didn't .. )

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is get the FluorineFX source code, set a few breakpoints and try to figure it out like that.